# How to popup json data in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

```
  "devices": [
    {
      "sub_family": "6s Plus",
      "presales_description": "iPhone 6 Plus features a stunning 5.5-inch Retina HD display, amazing cameras and many advanced features, all in a breakthrough design. A 5.5-inch Retina HD display. An A8 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. 8MP iSight camera with Focus Pixels and optical image stabilisation. Touch ID. Fast 4G LTE and Wi-Fi.1 Long battery life.2 And iOS 9 and iCloud.",
      "Camera": true,
      "device_type": "smartphone",
      "presales_vendor": "Apple",
      "sim_form-factor": "Nano",
      "memory": 64,
      "device_class": "HC14",
      "TV Capable": true,
      "family": "iPhone",
      "specification_reference": "D20",
      "variants": [
        {
          "colour": "Space Grey",
          "default": true,
          "presales_sequence": 961,
          "s_code": "S0346715",
          "credit_risk": 750,
          "colour_code": "#898989",
          "max_credit_term": 24,
          "list_price": 759,
          "presales_start_date": "02/04/2016"
        },
        {
          "colour": "Silver",
          "default": true,
          "presales_sequence": 961,
          "s_code": "S0346717",
          "credit_risk": 750,
          "colour_code": "#e5e5e5",
          "max_credit_term": 24,
          "list_price": 759,
          "presales_start_date": "02/04/2016"
        }]}
```

This is  the code I tried:

```
<a ng-click="showDialog(x)" >View full spec </a>
<div id="modalOpen" class="modalClass" >
<div class="modalDesc">
<a ng-click="closeDialog()" class="closeModal">x</a>
<div>
<ul> <li ng-repeat="data in x.variants">{{data.colour}}</li> </ul>
</div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: I want to populate colors on popup

Comment: What do you mean you want to popup data?

Comment: please do some research on how to show a popup in angular js, then try some code. If you get any error on that code or you didn't understand something, then paste you code so that we can help.